# How can I disable routing between interfaces by default on pfSense?

Tags: pfsense

By default, pfSense routes traffic between WAN, LAN, OPT1, OPT2, ...

Currently I am explicitly blocking certain combinations via firewall rules.

**How can I configure pfSense to use a whitelisting approach instead (only allowing necessary combinations)?**

Comment: [*"The default on all interfaces is to deny traffic, and only what is explicitly allowed via firewall rules will be passed."*](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Firewall_Rule_Basics) - are you sure you haven't messed up your firewall rules?

Comment: @the-wabbit If you've configured an interface to allow traffic out to the Internet, then that rule will probably allow traffic through to subnets on other interfaces as well, unless you've carefully locked it down or perhaps set a gateway.

Answer (score 2):

Everything is a default deny. Nothing is allowed that you aren't passing via your configured rules.

The way to disable routing is to block the traffic you don't want routed. An alias containing RFC1918 is helpful to block traffic to non-Internet destinations. It's also possible to use the alias in your pass rules as a "not" destination, but it's usually more logically clear to people if you just put in a single block and allow destination "any" for the Internet.

Comment: Note: a rule like this will also block traffic to the interface's own subnet - which *the firewall itself* is probably listening on.  Be mindful of this if you need to connect to it, or ask it for a DHCP lease, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you copied the default rules from LAN to OPT1 and OPT2 you can do the following to block traffic between network interfaces:

**Example that prevents traffic originating in OPT1 from reaching LAN traffic**
Create a rule under OPT1 to "block", protocol "any" source "OPT1 net" destination "LAN net".

Follow the same pattern for the other interfaces.